# How to combine multiple notifications of the same kind

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have an iOS app that shows the user a set of different news feeds in a PageViewController. Everytime the app starts, it requests the news data from the backend for every single feed. In case it worked fine, a notification via for every single news feed is sent via NSNotificationCenter so the data can be displayed. 
In case of an error, a notification for every single feed is sent as well, triggering a popup message that tells the user something went wrong. But if this happens, a popup will be shown for every news feed, up to the amount of added news feeds.

My question is, how can I combine all those error case notifications to a single one and therefore avoid having many useless and annyoing popups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (self.isShowingErrorDialog) {
    return;  // Or possibly cache to show after current one is dismissed.
} else {
    [[UIAlertView ...] show];
    self.showingErrorDialog = YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick reply. I tried your code, but my controller doesn't have a **isShowingErrorDialog** attribute. I also don't fully understand this approach. Should every controller check if it's showing a popup message and if so, suppress showing it?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  You would need to add that as a BOOL property on your class.  It originally sounded as if you had a single place that handled the notifications and displayed the errors.  My suggestion is to keep track of whether or not you're showing an error at that choke point.  If you have lots of places that are doing it, you'd need to synchronize them somehow, e.g. delegate to a singleton object that is responsible for displaying the UI, or use a mutex or something.

Comment: I basically followed your suggestion and check if the controller currently shows an error message. If so, I set a **showErrorDialog** flag and ignore the following error messages. In order to make that work, I moved the error message handling of all error messages to a single place in my **PageViewController** instead of having every **CollectonViewController** handle its own error message. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you send a notification using NSNotificationCentre, you can include user info.  This is basically an NSDictionary with additional information.

Why not just include the timestamp of the failed request.  You can test this with some fuzziness to see if you've already put up an alert for this batch of requests.

```
- (void) notificationListener: (NSNotification*) notification {

    static NSDate* lastAlerted = nil;
    NSDate* sentDate = notification.userInfo[@"RequestDate"];

    if ( lastAlerted != nil && [lastAlerted timeIntervalSince:sentDate] > FUZZY_INTERVAL) {
        // post alert

        // And update last Alerted
        lastAlerted = sentDate;
    }

}
```

The method you need is postNotificationWithName:Object:UserInfo:.

Gordon

<s>I don't think you can.</s>

Just to confirm, the notifications you're sending are Apple remote notifications and the alerts are the system alerts popped up by the message centre.

The alerts occur before you get control, as the user has to have the opportunity to ignore them, or else people would use this as a cheat to make apps run in the background and kill user's batteries.

All you can do is send a batch token in your request, and check on the back end.

Good luck

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry, I should have pointed this out earlier. I'm using NSNotificationCenter to let my controllers know that fresh data has been retrieved from the backend, or in case of an error, that a popup message has to be raised.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I find this a very helpful suggestion which I can use on a similar problem.